# why Intellij is showing compile time issue, even-though maven is OK

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I am working on intellij first time my application is running through maven but intellij is showing compiler error Like:
[image]

Here is POM.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example.api</groupId>
<artifactId>api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>api</name>
<description>let's solve together</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <immutable.version>2.8.3</immutable.version>
    <asciidoctor-plugin.version>1.5.8</asciidoctor-plugin.version>
    <rest.doc.plugin.version>2.0.4.RELEASE</rest.doc.plugin.version>
    <maven.resource.plugin.version>2.7</maven.resource.plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <jjwt.version>0.9.1</jjwt.version>
    <aws-s3-version>1.11.780</aws-s3-version>
    <commons.fileupload.version>1.4</commons.fileupload.version>
    <docker-maven-version>1.4.13</docker-maven-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
        <artifactId>value</artifactId>
        <version>${immutable.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>${aws-s3-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>${commons.fileupload.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!--<configuration>
                <finalName>Brainy-API</finalName>
            </configuration>-->
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerVersion>${java.version}</compilerVersion>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
                        <artifactId>value</artifactId>
                        <version>${immutable.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <!-- Prevents an endPosTable exception during compilation -->
                <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${asciidoctor-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-docs</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <backend>html</backend>
                        <doctype>book</doctype>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                    <version>${rest.doc.plugin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.resource.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.outputDirectory}/static/docs
                        </outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>
                                    ${project.build.directory}/generated-docs
                                </directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

anyone please share suggestions

Comment: There is no compilation error here.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider :- its not resolving javax and other packages as well, any suggestion

Comment: @SandeepTiwari first of all, please post code snippets, instead of pictures. What about scopes of your dependencies? can you share your pom.xml?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I have added pom.xml, could you please check?

Comment: try File | New | Project from Existing Sources... action and select pom.xml file to import project from to re-created the project's configuration. Does it help?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like pom.xml dependencies are not synced yet. Reload project once from Maven window -> Reload project. It will reload your project with fresh dependencies again and your imports package issue will go away.

Comment: no, thats not working have done multiple times, also removed .m2 and install fresh but  its not wen away

Comment: Are you using system installed maven or IntelliJ idea installed maven to build project?
Which version are you using for maven?